# Bundle install failing with mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

I'm trying to get mysql2 to install.

I have added this to my config:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/bin/mysql_config
```

but receive this error when running bundle install:

```
Installing mysql2 0.3.12b5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/click/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150901-49830-hf7d1e.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/bin/mysql_config
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:39:
In file included from ./client.h:11:
/Users/click/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward/rubysig.h:14:2: warning: rubysig.h is obsolete [-W#warnings]
#warning rubysig.h is obsolete
^
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:39:
./client.h:13:14: warning: redefinition of typedef 'rb_unblock_function_t' is a C11 feature [-Wtypedef-redefinition]
typedef void rb_unblock_function_t(void *);
         ^
/Users/click/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:897:14: note: previous definition is here
typedef void rb_unblock_function_t(void *);
         ^
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:39:
./client.h:14:15: warning: redefinition of typedef 'rb_blocking_function_t' is a C11 feature [-Wtypedef-redefinition]
typedef VALUE rb_blocking_function_t(void *);
          ^
/Users/click/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/intern.h:898:15: note: previous definition is here
typedef VALUE rb_blocking_function_t(void *);
          ^
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:39:
./client.h:23:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TRAP_BEG'
TRAP_BEG;
^
./client.h:25:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TRAP_END'
TRAP_END;
^
3 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/click/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.12b5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/click/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.12b5/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.12b5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.12b5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have searched for solutions relating to rb_thread_blocking_region() but have not found any working solution.

Ruby: ruby 2.2.1p85.

Installed mysql with Brew.

Update:

I was able to add the extra flags needed to the bundle configuration which allows me to run bundle install fine.

You can configure bundle to build mysql2 with your local mysql's headers and set flags to solve the rb_thread_blocking_region:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.26/bin/mysql_config --with-cflags=\"-DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION\"
```

However, when I run a sphinx search, I get this error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_blocking_region
Referenced from: /Users/click/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.12b5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_blocking_region
Referenced from: /Users/click/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.12b5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    61566 trace trap  rails s
```

Comment: Lets see the command you used to install mysql.  On ubuntu using apt-get, the command is: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev`.  Note that there are some libraries in addition to the base package.  I suspect you are running into something similar.

Comment: @Daiku OP is clearly not on Ubuntu and this line `checking for mysql.h... yes` clearly stated that mysql-dev was installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [compiler error while installing rubygem 'mysql2' in Ruby 1.9.2 over CentOS 64-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453102/compiler-error-while-installing-rubygem-mysql2-in-ruby-1-9-2-over-centos-64-bi)